# Port Forwarding on unavoidable Double-NAT pfSense

Tags: lan, pfsense

I've got a pfSense box which is acting as DHCP/DNS for one LAN, which all office computers and servers connect to.

We have a modem which cannot be put into bridge mode for several reasons and cannot be swapped out for another bridgeable modem as we use certain services from the ISP that only function with their (rather crappy) modem.

We can, however assign a PC on the Modem's LAN to be a DMZ, which I've done, selecting the pfSense box as DMZ, no other devices other than this are on the Modem's LAN.

The issue I face is this: I can't port forward from the pfSense box to any other computer/server on the pfSense LAN. I confirmed that the Modem's DMZ is working as I connected a server directly to the Modem's LAN and was able to access services from our public IP. Also, we used to use a Windows server for DHCP and Routing and Remote Access, which included a **very** basic port forward function which did work. The only thing we've changed is the installation of the pfSense box as the Windows server died.

How do I port forward using pfSense under these conditions.

Comment: Why use NAT on the router? It sounds like the modem is doing NAT. You only need to NAT once.

Comment: We don't want people to be able to access certain ISP-provided devices on the Modem's LAN network, which has proved to be an issue in the past. We also run two network boot services (one Windows PXE, one Apple NetInstall) which we can't get working on the ISP's Modem, but has always worked on a third-party router/pfSense.

Comment: You can use the firewall to prevent that, and use the pfSense router, without using NAT. I really don't see the need for the second NAT.

Comment: Another issue is the very limited interface you have on the ISP's Modem, you get either one PC as a DMZ or a small preset list of no-custom-ports-allowed services to port forward to multiple computers.

Comment: The solution to me was to add a better router in place to deal with the limitations of the Modem, which had worked until now, which is something I cannot figure out after trying a variety of configurations on pfSense.

Comment: A second NAT doesn't help with your modem limitations. You are just making things harder than they need to be. You really don't need to NAT on pfSense for the router or firewall to work.

Comment: Okay, if the secondary NAT is the issue, how do I disable NAT functionality on pfSense, I've just had a peek in likely places, not there.

Comment: It's right in the [documentation](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Outbound_NAT#Disable_NAT).

Comment: For once I disagree with Ron, you need NAT because the ISP modem will likely not NAT another subnet that its own (and have no route to them anyway). I had to do this for several customers and usually double-NAT works just fine.

Comment: @JFL, I really don't have any information that a different subnet is needed. If the network the modem provides is only what is needed, then a second NAT is not necessary. It's just that so many people think you must NAT on a firewall, but that just isn't true.

Comment: @Ron I get your point, if there's only one subnet then the ISP modem can handle it, but that means you rely on their firewalling and the limited feature set they provide.  You cannot use your own firewall, that means less security and visibility / monitoring. What if you have a single public IP and want to PAT two different services to two different servers?

Comment: @JFL, there is no reason you can have a firewall between the modem and users. Many firewalls don't need to have different networks on each side.

Comment: I've left the office and will try Ron's answer tomorrow, just some information, the pfSense DHCP range is 192.168.1.1-254 and the Modem's range is 192.168.15.1, with .2 being the WAN interface of the pfSense box.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you really just need to disable NAT on the pfSense router/firewall. You simply don't need to use NAT to route or use the firewall. You can use the firewall to disallow users from accessing the ISP services, and you get the boot services that work on pfSense. This should solve the double-NAT port forwarding problem.

The [pfSense documentation](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Outbound_NAT#Disable_NAT) tell you how to disable the firewall:

> ## Disable NAT
>
> ---
>
> To completely disable NAT to have a routing-only firewall, do the
>   following.
>
> ### pfSense 2.2 And Later
>
> ---
>
> 1. Navigate to Firewall > NAT on the Outbound tab
> 2. Select Disable Outbound NAT rule generation (No Outbound NAT rules)
> 3. Click Save
> 4. Apply changes
>
> ### Prior Versions
>
> ---
>
> 1. Navigate to Firewall > NAT on the Outbound tab
> 2. Select Manual Outbound NAT rule generation (Advanced Outbound NAT
>      (AON))
> 3. Click Save
> 4. Delete all rules from the list on the page
> 5. Click Apply changes
>
> NAT may be performed on some interfaces and not others by configuring
>   Outbound NAT rules accordingly.
>
> Details may be found in [the pfSense book](http://pfsense.org/book).

Comment: Disabling NAT has the effect of preventing PCs on the pfSense LAN from connecting to the internet.

Comment: You must be keeping a separate local network from the network assigned by the modem. If you let the modem assign the network and addresses, you should have no problem. Set up pfSense as a layer-2 firewall. I get the impression you don't understand what is going on or how networking actually works.

Comment: I have a pretty basic knowledge of networking, this is true. The thing is, the windows server was able to work/port forward in this environment, while the pfSense one is having difficulty doing so. We require DHCP on the pfSense box to be enabled/have it assign addresses as we have DHCP options that need to be set in order for some PCs to discover the PXE server.

Comment: If pfSense is the source of your trouble, you need to replace it with a router which works. You could block DHCP messages at the layer-2 pfSense firewall so that the modem never sees them, and let pfSense still perform DHCP. DHCP servers built into routers are really a sort of last resort. Normally, you want a dedicated DHCP server, even if it is only a VM in a physical server.

Comment: At this current point in time, doing a major overhaul and change/spinning up a new VM isn't possible. I would just like to see if anyone can tell me what you need to do with pfSense to get it to port forward properly under these conditions.

Comment: You have not put any configuration which you have tried, and where it fails for you, in your question. You need to describe what you have tried, and what your specific problem with it is. Include any logs or test to show the problem.

Comment: @ThomasJones, by the way, as I wrote, you can still use the pfSense DHCP server to assign host addresses in the network which the modem defines. Just block the the DHCP requests/replies on the firewall, configured as a layer-2 firewall, from traveling to/from the modem.

Comment: And just to make sure you are not now dealing with CGN, what are the first two octets of your IPv4 WAN address?

Comment: 101.187 is the beginning of my public IP address.

Comment: I'm not asking about the public address. What address is assigned on the ISP side of the modem. Those can be different addresses. A user where the ISP has used CGN can find his public address by going to a website, but that is not the address which the ISP has assigned to the user.

Comment: They are one in the same address.

Comment: OK. I just wanted to make sure the the ISP didn't start using CGN. That is happening more and more. If double-NAT isn't working for you with pfSense, you may need to look at a better router.

Comment: Just seems so strange and unnecessarily difficult to me, there MUST be a way around this issue, some quick hack or hotfix or PHP code patch...

Comment: Did you ask about bugs or patches on the pfSense forums? CGN would explain why it doesn't work since you can't forward on the ISP NAT. I did give you a workaround (layer-2 firewall blocking DHCP from the modem).

Comment: Layer-2 firewall that blocks DHCP from the modem seems overly complicated, it's already more complicated as it is now.

Comment: Not particularly complicated. A firewall should block DHCP by default, as yours seems to do. You just need to set it up as a layer-2 firewall instead of a layer-3 firewall. Basically, just turn off routing on pfSense.